# Finite difference methods comparison lemma

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods

I am sorry to post this with such little attempt from myself. I assure you, that if I have anything come to me, I will update with my own input. I was going through my course notes and came across the attached Corollary. I have no idea on how to prove it! Thank you and kindest regards!

**Corollary 2.21 text:**

Let $u(x)\le0$ for $x\in\gamma_{h}$ and $L_{h}u(x)\le0$ (or $u(x)\ge0$ for $x\in\gamma_{h}$ and $L_{h}u(x)\ge0$, respectively) on $\omega_{h}$ . Assume that there is at least one inner node close to the boundary $x^{*}$ and one node $x_{\gamma}$ on the boundary with $b(x^{*},x_{\gamma})>0$. Then, the grid function $u(x)$ is non-positive (or non-negative, respectively) for all $x\in\omega_{h}\cup\gamma_{h}$

**The question:**

Let the assumptions from Corollary 2.21 be satisfied and let

$$\begin{array}{c}{{{L}_{h}u(x)=f(x)\ f o r\ x\in\omega_{h};\quad u(x)=g(x)\ f o r\ x\in\gamma_{h},}}\\ {{{ L}_{h}{\bar{u}}(x)={\bar{f}}(x)\ f o r\ x\in\omega_{h};\quad{\bar{u}}(x)={\bar{g}}(x)\ f o r\ x\in\gamma_{h},}}\end{array}$$

with

$$\lvert{f({x})}\rvert\leq\bar{f}(x),x\in\omega_{h}$$

$$\lvert{g({x})}\rvert\leq\bar{g}(x),x\in\gamma_{h}$$

then

$\lvert{u({x})}\rvert\leq\bar{u}(x)$ for all $x\in\omega_{h}\cup\gamma_{h}.$

**Notation**
$L_{h}:$ A differential operator,

$\omega_{h}^{\circ}:$ Inner nodes of a grid function,

$\omega_{h}^{*}:$ Inner nodes close to the boundary of a grid function

$\gamma_{h}:$ Boundary nodes of a grid function

$$\omega_{h}:\omega_{h}^{\circ}\cup\omega_{h}^{*}$$

Comment: Thank you, I have managed to reformat the question using mathjax. For whatever reason, when I was attempting to write this post earlier, my inputs were not recognised at all. Hopefully they are easier to read now

Comment: $L_h$ is the discretization of an elliptical operator? On the whole this is about some kind of maximum principle? Is there a connection to variational calculus? What is $b$, is there some "geometric" interpretation of this condition?

Comment: Consider $u-\bar u$ and $-u-\bar u$. Then with $\pm f-\bar f\le 0$ and $\pm g-\bar g\le 0$ all assumptions of 2.21 are satisfied, so that indeed also $\pm u-\bar u\le 0$.